# é character not working properly in wordpress Image URL

Tags: php, wordpress, image, unicode, character

Can any body tell me why below both image URL are acting different but looking same?

First one is showing not found 404 error but another one is working fine.

[http://www.francophonie-en-fete.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/métropolitain.jpg](http://www.francophonie-en-fete.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/m%C3%A9tropolitain.jpg)

[http://www.francophonie-en-fete.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/métropolitain.jpg](http://www.francophonie-en-fete.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/me%CC%81tropolitain.jpg)

Comment: "looking" the same is the operative term. There's many ways of accenting a char in unicode. base `e` plus various combining chars, or just flat-out selecting a codepoint that is "accented e". both would LOOK the same, but have different byte sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `é` is a single Unicode character [`é` (Latin Small Letter E with Acute)](http://unicode-table.com/en/00E9/).

Your second `é` is composed from two Unicode characters [`e` (Latin Small Letter E)](http://unicode-table.com/en/0065/) and [`́` (Combining Acute Accent)](http://unicode-table.com/en/0301/).

Answer (score 0):

On my browser, the second URL actually looks different, as it does not understand the encoding used in the second example (I'm using an US locale).

Technically, they are different, so they are addressing different file names. That should explain why the server that handles the request can only resolve one of the URLs.